# I have a table to which i need all the values of the td element

Tags: jquery

My code is below i have a table, 
following is the jsp & jquery code, i need the value of input , i click the button of the row and get all elements, but the input value is not retrieved, plz help.

```
<tbody> 
<s:iterator  value="selectedProductList">  
<tr >
    <td><s:property value="selectedProductName"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="selectedProductWt"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="selectedProductPrice"/></td> 
    <td><s:textfield name = "productQuantity" maxlength="2" value = "1"></s:textfield>

</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

```
$(".buttonPick").click(function() {


    var $rowItem = $(this).parent().parent();
    var $closestTr = $rowItem.closest("tr");  
    var $tds = $closestTr.find("td"); 
    var i = 0;
    $.each($tds, function() {              
     if(i==0)
         values.push($(this).text());
     if(i==2)
         values.push($(this).text());
     if(i==3)
         values.push($(this).text());
     if(i==4){
         //values.push($(this).text()); ... what do i do here???
     }

    i++;    
});
```

Comment: where is `$(".buttonPick")` element in html ?

Comment: What's the difference between all these if's? They all do the same... So maybe `if(i==4) { values.push($(this).text()); }`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find("input").val()
```

Use this to fetch the value of `input` inside the `td`, and I do not think that `if-conditions` are making any sense here.